# Detecting non tagged textarea or input fields

Tags: javascript

I made a Chrome Extension that allowed me to change certain characters if certain keystroke combinations were made to any input or text area field. It works fine as long as what I am typing in is a input or textarea field. However, when I go to a site like FaceBook and try their post or comments field, it doesn't work because those fields somehow don't have textarea tags in their source.

Here is what I currently use.

```
document.activeElement.onkeydown = function(){ getCharKeyDown(event) }; 
document.activeElement.onkeyup = function(){ getCharKeyUp(event) };
```

What would I need to do, to detect if a user is typing in a textarea that doesn't seem to actually be a text area (in plain JavaScript please)?

Thanks.

Comment: If you inspect source on the comment field, what is it? It has to be some type of element...

Comment: well your code should be `function(event){ getCharKeyDown(event) };` And you are not typing in a textarea, but a contenteditable element

Comment: The FB post field seems to be mostly divs, spans, and tables(!?) 
Here is a text dump https://pastebin.com/udCsP64q

Comment: I've never heard of this contenteditable element before. Just reading about it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello), I think I've got it sorted. After a bit of reading about the HTMLElement.contentEditable property, I came across Document.execCommand() which seems to take care of all editable elements.

This was the main change I made

```
function insertAtCursor(myField, myValue) {
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, myValue);
}
```

and now I am able to run my functions wherever.